# Can't go to jail in Markarth

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, xbox-360

I've killed a jailer in Markarth. Well I went werewolf and slaughtered everybody in the Minra mines or however you pronounce it. Much later in the game I killed a whole caravan of Imperial Eleves, didn't like their tone with me and slaughtered them on the spot, I was watched by two bystanders and I left.

I later met with guards near Markarth saying that I had been caught for those crimes. I agreed to go to jail, but it never takes me there, I just end up going back to the dialogue box with my question to the guard "How can I help you?". I can basically go into an infinite loop of saying "Take me to jail" and he never takes me there. I really have some unfinished business in that city.

Is there a Leupold around this?

Comment: Is "Leupold" some term in Skyrim I'm not familiar with, or do you perhaps mean "loophole"?

Comment: Of all the times for the murder tag to have been removed...

Comment: lol yeah that's precisely what i meant, my bad

Comment: I am wondering about this myself did the achievement for the master criminal now i cant even go into town without it bugging out just repeats the whole dialog over and over with like 6 guards circling me. I know this one is on the xbox but i am using the PC version of the game.

Answer (score 4):

The Markarth Guard glitch can happen after completing the two Falmar quests. There are several ways of combating this bug other than reloading a previous save file:

- Revisit the Shrine of Talos in Markath and clearing out the gaurds
  again.
- Trade Markarth for Riften at the [peace talks](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Season_Unending).
- Become Thane of the Reach.

The bug is listed on Bethesda's forum in the [bug report topic](http://forums.bethsoft.com/index.php?/topic/1298524-xbox-360-bug-report-topic/).

Comment: I had this glitch too and re-entering the Shrine of Talos fixed it. Finally some guards in there arrested me and it fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem, so I loaded an old save. Then, I did the quest up to the part where the guards kill the guy in the temple. During the conversation with them about me being arrested, I noticed I could press the back button. I did and the guards let me buy my way out for 1,000 gold.